# Can't find downloaded TensorFlow dataset in google collab in the directory

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow-datasets

I am downloading the Stanford dogs dataset in collab and it says that it is prepared to `~/tensorflow_datasets/stanford_dogs/0.2.0` but that folder does not appear to exist in the root directory on the collab. What am I missing? The code is below:

```
dataset, metadata = tfds.load('stanford_dogs', as_supervised=True, with_info=True)
train_dataset, test_dataset = dataset['train'], dataset['test']
```

Downloading and preparing dataset 778.12 MiB (download: 778.12 MiB, generated: Unknown size, total: 778.12 MiB) to ~/tensorflow_datasets/stanford_dogs/0.2.0...
Dataset stanford_dogs downloaded and prepared to ~/tensorflow_datasets/stanford_dogs/0.2.0. Subsequent calls will reuse this data.

```
cd ~/tensorflow_datasets/stanford_dogs/0.2.0
```

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/tensorflow_datasets/stanford_dogs/0.2.0'
/root

Answer (score 0):

Just copy that root directory as a string in new cell, then do ctrl+click on it to navigate to it:

[testDir='/root/tensorflow_datasets/stanford_dogs/0.2.0'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E46HG.jpg)